# Input from keyboard the <enter>

Tags: python

I use Python 3 in Windows. My problem is that I need to find out how can I put in my code the choice that if the user pushes the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key the program will continue doing the calculation and when the user types <kbd>q</kbd> and pushes the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key the program will be terminated.

A simple code is below.

```
while True:
    x = int(input('Give number: '))
    y=x*3
    print(y)
```

Comment: If you need to test that the input is the empty string or the 'q' string then don't immediately convert it to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    s = input('Give number: ')
    if s == 'q':
       break
    y=int(s)*3
    print(y)
```

Comment: Thank you it really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
        user_input = input('Give number: ')
        if not user_input.isdigit(): #alternatively if user_input != 'q'
           break
        x = int(user_input)
        y=x*3
        print(y)
```

Assuming you want to calculate while new numbers are entered, the `str` `isdigit` function returns `True` if the string only contains digits. This approach will allow you to handle if the user enters a non-integer like `xsd`, which will crash the program if you try to cast to int. To only exit if `q` is entered, you would do `if user_input != 'q'`, but this assumes the user only enters numbers or `q`.